# How to notify when a checkbox is checked

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, vba

Change on checkbox is not recognized when the check is performed by custom function.

We have form where checkboxes can be clicked. In this case the record will be added to a list, which will be updated with a save function. And there is mentioned function to check all check boxes, but this does not behave like when i click an individual checkbox.

code "Select all"

```
Private Sub Befehl83_Click()
    With Me.RecordsetClone
        .MoveFirst
        Do Until .EOF
            .Edit
            !visited = True
            .update
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

clicked on checkbox

```
Private Sub chkVisited_Click()
    If Not visitedList.Contains(Me.Form.Recordset.Fields("trainingMeasureID").Value) Then
        visitedList.Add Me.Form.Recordset.Fields("trainingMeasureID").Value
    Else
        visitedList.Remove Me.Form.Recordset.Fields("trainingMeasureID").Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Currently the state of checkboxes is not saved when used the select-all function. Only when a checkbox is selected individually.

It should save correctly in both cases.

Comment: You'd better re-populate the list after selecting/deselecting all checkboxes, don't do this individually in the loop for selecting all

Answer (score 0):

Use the *AfterUpdate* event:

```
Private Sub Befehl83_Click()

    With Me.RecordsetClone
        .MoveFirst
        Do Until .EOF
            If !visited.Value = False Then
                .Edit
                !visited.Value = True
                .update
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Actually there is no Update-Option on Checkbox.

Comment: It's not an "update", it's an Event. Listed in the properties.

Comment: I found out that its a button Like checkbox,..not  real checkbox.... mmhh So there is no update

Comment: OK. I've updated the answer - now very close to yours. It _will_ work - with no requery or refresh. If not, then something else is going on.

Comment: thanks gustav. Well as jbud mentioned, RecordsetClone only provides a readonly-set. So his answer is a bit more correct than your suggestion.

Comment: I don't know why you believe _RecordsetClone_ is read-only. It is not if, of course, the form is updatable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a not so ideal solution:

```
Private Sub Befehl83_Click()
    With Me.Recordset
        .MoveFirst
        Do Until .EOF
            .Edit
            .Fields("visited") = True
            .Update
            Call chkVisited_Click()
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

This will actively update the record set, you'll actually see the active record moving in the form.

Another solution would be to rebuild your code and do your updates directly to the underlying data source based on your form's recordset. Then update your list accordingly.

According to the docs, RecordsetClone is a read-only copy of the form's recordset. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.recordsetclone

Comment: But that is not the case. The documention is not correct, can't tell why.

Comment: I'm guessing you're referring to the read-only state of the RecordsetClone property of the form. It really depends on how you look at it, from the form's perspective it's indeed read-only, since any changes to the cloned recordset will not reflect in the form's recordset. From the perspective of the underlying tables, yes data will be updated, if it's a updateable recordset.

Comment: No, I'm not referring to anything - except the faulty documentation page. For the RecordsetClone, you somehow have got it mixed up: Any change made to this _is_ reflected at once in the form without a requery.